# my css style works on the same page as the element, but not when linked from .css file

Tags: html, css

I have a page with elements on it, a ton of them, and one of them is inside a couple divs. the one i wasnt to target has certain styles i want attributed to it, when i style inline on the page itself, the styles work, but when i link to the stylesheet it doesnt change the style to how i want it. im not sure why, thanks for your help.

**Here is my inline code:**

```
profile_pic_box {
    float:left; 
    border:#999 2px solid; 
    width:100px; 
    height:100px; 
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; 
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

This works fine when i have it on the page that the element is contained on, but when I remove the code and place it on a style sheet, which is linked correctly, it doesn't work. Here is what I have in a stylesheet:

**style.css**:

```
#profile_pic_box {
    float:left; 
    border:#999 2px solid; 
    width:100px; 
    height:100px; 
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; 
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

Here is some HTML:

```
<div id="profile_pic_box">
```

And here is the stylesheet link, which does work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
```

Comment: Is `profile_pic_box` an ID? because in your inline style, there is no #.

Comment: using your browser console, do you see your css file included ? If not it means that it's not linked correctly.

Comment: Please post your HTML code.

Comment: profile_pic_box is an id and it works when its inline, without the #.  the css file is included correctly, because other styles are working with it. what part of my html code would be helpful, there are hundreds of lines

Comment: If `profile_pic_box` really is an ID, then there is no way that it can work without the hashtag. Please just include a section of your HTML that contains an example of `profile_pic_box`.

Comment: should it be: div#profile_pic_box {
 float:left; 
 border:#999 2px solid; 
 width:100px; 
 height:100px; 
 margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; 
 overflow-y:hidden;
}

Comment: That would make your style more specific, but it probably wouldn't address the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of the following:

- Your browser is caching the old **style.css** file. Try disabling cache in developer tools or open the website in an incognito tab.
- You're adding your CSS before another CSS that's possibly overwriting it. In-line works because it is at an higher level.
- Not sure if you're running it on a server or not, but you also could try adding a slash at the beginning of your href like this:

  href="/style/style.css"

Comment: so, now what it looks like, is that my style sheet isnt linking properyl. stylesheet is in a folder called 'style' and in that folder is 'stylesheet.css' but i cang get the path right. the user page is in the bottom level, below the 'style' folder. how do i get it to work?

Comment: @user3790696: I can't understand 100% what's your exact target and issue now. But do are trying to reach something like: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/stylesheet.css">`? or `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/stylesheet.css">`?

Answer (score 0):

```css
#profile_pic_box {
    float:left; 
    border:#999 2px solid; 
    width:100px; 
    height:100px; 
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; 
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">

<div id="profile_pic_box">
```

Comment: pls chk the above